# error: constructor is private

Tags: c++

litte question:

here is the class:

```
class Author 
{

    Author(const std::string& name, const std::string& email, Gender gender);
    Author& setName(const std::string& name);

private:
    std::string a_name;
    std::string a_email;
    int a_gender;
}
```

and i don't know why, he is write the next error:

error: 'Author::Author(const string&, const string&, Gender)' is private|

but it is defently constructor, so what is privet for him so he can't get acsses?

tanks!

Comment: put public: in front of the constructors

Comment: Or replace `class` by `struct`. And add a trailing `;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access in a `class` defaults to `private:`, not `public:`.

This:

```
class Author 
{

    Author(const std::string& name, const std::string& email, Gender gender);
    Author& setName(const std::string& name);
```

Should be:

```
class Author 
{
  public:
    Author(const std::string& name, const std::string& email, Gender gender);
    Author& setName(const std::string& name);
```